# Sidewaystable* captions in MNRAS class

Tags: sidewaystable

I have a table that is slightly too wide, so I am putting it in landscape mode. After playing a bit with the landscape object class, I am unhappy with the results (e.g. the tables are not floating nicely). Therefore, I am now trying to get the sidewaystable working.

Since I want them to take an entire page (and as it is a two column document) I use sidewaystable*, which is almost perfect, except for a very cryptic error I get in the caption.

```
\sf@old@caption ...espaces #3}\else \@makecaption 
                                                  {\csname fnum@#1\endcsname...
```

And the fact that the caption label is not bold and has no separation with the caption text.

[image: Caption]

This is the piece of code that is relevant:

```
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\caption{a caption}
\centering
\label{tab:jet_parameters}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}
```

In the preamble I have tried both the rotation + float packages and the rotfloat package. It makes no difference.

It is a \documentclass[fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras} document.

Do you have any idea of how to debug this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

For the `mnras` class it is better follow the Instructions to Authors:

> To produce a landscape figure or table, use the `pdflscape` package
> and the `landscape` environment.
>
> Unfortunately this method will force a page break before the table
> appears. More complicated solutions are possible, but authors
> shouldn't worry about this.

[image: a]

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{An example landscape table.}
        \label{tab:landscape}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
            \hline
            Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header\\
            Unit & Unit & Unit & Unit & Unit & Unit & Unit & Unit & Unit & Unit \\
            \hline
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it in the past but I gave it up because of the forced page-break. Now I see this is a non-issue for MNRAS, I should have read the manual more carefully.